# Google Analytics - Unable to get GA Tracking

Tags: google-analytics

We've been using GA for a few years with no probs. About 2-3 weeks ago we tried to clean up some of our tracking and on one of our profiles, it's not working anymore (since oct 10.)

First, some context then some GA Debugging code.

#### 1. Context.

We have the following setup: different root domains AND different sub-domains on one of the root domains.

> 1. www.website.com
> 2. www.website.com.au
> 3. www.anotherWebsite.com
> 4. foo.website.com
> 5. baa.website.com

So what we're doing is the following:

1. each root domain and each sub-domain get their own tracking code. This way we can allow separate people (from outside our company) to access only their own data. Eg. a manager for foo.website.com can only see data related to that domain .. and see data on the other domains.
2. Have a last account which is the SUM of all the domains. this is for us. so we can see total numbers.

So to do this, we have two trackers that fire off, on the page.

- the individual accounts all work fine - they seem to be tracking data ok.
- the 'global' account is not working and this gives us the => Tracking Not Installed error.

This has been going on since oct 10. So the *wait 24/48/72 hours thing* is waaaaay over.

#### 2. GA Debug code.

Installing `GA Debug chrome extension` gives the following output. I've tried to hide anything that could be considered secret.

```
UA-XXXXX34-1 == Global account (which isn't working any more).
UA-XXXXX34-11 == Specific account for www.website.com

_gaq.push processing "_setAccount" for args: "[UA-XXXXX34-1]":  ga_debug.js:18
_gaq.push processing "_setDomainName" for args: "[website.com]":  ga_debug.js:18
_gaq.push processing "_setAllowLinker" for args: "[true]":  ga_debug.js:18
_gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]":  ga_debug.js:18
Track Pageview ga_debug.js:18
Tracking beacon sent!
utmwv=--snipped--
Account ID               : UA-XXXX234-1
Page Title               : Some page title
Host Name                : www.website.com
Page                     : /
Referring URL            : -
Hit ID                   : 1923583969
Visitor ID               : 785310647
Session Count            : 51
Session Time - First     : Thu Aug 23 2012 15:20:17 GMT 1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)
Session Time - Last      : Mon Oct 29 2012 11:41:46 GMT 1100 (AUS Eastern Summer Time)
Session Time - Current   : Mon Oct 29 2012 12:19:23 GMT 1100 (AUS Eastern Summer Time)
Campaign Time            : Thu Aug 23 2012 15:20:17 GMT 1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)
Campaign Session         : 1
Campaign Count           : 1
Campaign Source          : (direct)
Campaign Medium          : (none);
Campaign Name            : (direct)
Language                 : en-gb
Encoding                 : UTF-8
Flash Version            : 11.4 r31
Java Enabled             : true
Screen Resolution        : 1050x1680
Browser Size             : 1033x861
Color Depth              : 32-bit
Ga.js Version            : 5.3.7d
Cachebuster              : 1846514973 ga_debug.js:18
_gaq.push processing "_setAccount" for args: "[UA-XXXX234-11]":  ga_debug.js:18
_gaq.push processing "_setDomainName" for args: "[website.com]":  ga_debug.js:18
_gaq.push processing "_setAllowLinker" for args: "[true]":  ga_debug.js:18
_gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]":  ga_debug.js:18
Track Pageview ga_debug.js:18
Tracking beacon sent!
utmwv=--snipped--
Account ID               : UA-XXXX234-11
Page Title               : SomePageTitle
Host Name                : www.website.com
Page                     : /
Referring URL            : -
Hit ID                   : 1923583969
Visitor ID               : 785310647
Session Count            : 51
Session Time - First     : Thu Aug 23 2012 15:20:17 GMT 1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)
Session Time - Last      : Mon Oct 29 2012 11:41:46 GMT 1100 (AUS Eastern Summer Time)
Session Time - Current   : Mon Oct 29 2012 12:19:23 GMT 1100 (AUS Eastern Summer Time)
Campaign Time            : Thu Aug 23 2012 15:20:17 GMT 1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)
Campaign Session         : 1
Campaign Count           : 1
Campaign Source          : (direct)
Campaign Medium          : (none);
Campaign Name            : (direct)
Language                 : en-gb
Encoding                 : UTF-8
Flash Version            : 11.4 r31
Java Enabled             : true
Screen Resolution        : 1050x1680
Browser Size             : 1033x861
Color Depth              : 32-bit
Ga.js Version            : 5.3.7d
Cachebuster              : 1580443754
```

and this is the js code he have.

BTW, it is inside a  `<head></head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(
        ['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXX234-1'],
        ['_setDomainName', 'website.com'],
        ['_setAllowLinker', true],
        ['_trackPageview']
            ,['b._setAccount','UA-XXXX234-11'],
            ['b._setDomainName','website.com'],
            ['b._setAllowLinker',true],
            ['b._trackPageview']
    );
    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Finally, I've triple checked that the UA is the correct text. and yes, the global account is `-1` and the specific domain is `-11`.

Comment: Just to cover the bases, are there any JavaScript errors occurring on the page?

Comment: Nope. I'll add the website to the main post and if this gets answered i'll remove it again.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a more fundamental issue with how you are structuring your tracking.

There should only be one UA code on the page.

You can manage the different access views required easily by creating different profiles which all use the same UA code. You can then apply certain filters to certain profiles to filter out data which you do not want under that profile.

Note when creating the single UA code make sure to select for multiple domains and subdomains.

Comment: So i should have one single UA Code (which can allow all our crazy domains and subdomains). Then, create seperate profiles which have forced filters? and the users of those specific profiles can't change those filters?

Comment: Hey - Yes, only the admin can change what is setup on the filters and I presume the profiles that you are adding for other users don't need to be admins.

Comment: one thing I don't get about your suggested answer is that we've had 2 UA codes on the page for a long time now..... and its been double tracking, not probs. hmmmm

Comment: Hey - yes, it does work but it is not recommended and further down the line it might not work at all. Also it leaves you with issues similar to the problem you outlined above.